# How confident is confident?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, semantics

I'd always thought that "sure" and "certain" were close to synonymous, both meaning absence of doubt (with "certain" in a slightly higher register, and maybe a bit stronger), and that "confident" meant "sure enough to make the assumption for practical purposes, but not necessarily certain."

I'm surprised by the amount of disagreement, and I wonder, is my impression informed (or tainted) by familiarity with statistics, where a "confidence interval" is a common way of quantifying confidence, which implies it's often not 100%?

We are defining code values of "confirmed" and "unconfirmed" for medical conditions. We want the definition to reflect a high enough probability of presence to justify treatment, but not certainty (it could be disproven later).

Current definition
There is sufficient evidence to assert the presence of the subject's condition.

I think "assert" is imprecise (the unconfirmed case is "asserted," too), and we need to indicate a confidence level, e.g.,

There is sufficient evidence to support confidence that the condition is present in the subject.
or
There is sufficient evidence to assert the presence of the subject's condition with confidence.

Some felt that "confidence" implied "certainty."

Comment: This seems opinion-based; I don't think there's any precise threshold at which the word "confident" becomes applicable.

Comment: https://youtu.be/RV-6qbUHVww

Comment: Can you provide more detail of the specific context. Confidence doesn't depend solely on probability, but also consequences. If someone said, "I'm confident I know the answer to that quiz question" that might be a lower standard than "I'm confident that the gun isn't loaded".

Comment: The likelihood of an *event* happening might be sure or certain, but never confident, which is a property of an observer, not the event. Some example uses might help: "I'm using one of these words in a definition" so please post it.

Comment: Reopened as it's now clearer (thank you!), but I'm not sure that applying confidence to whether something is "confirmed" is actually a matter of English. It seems to me to be rather a matter of statistics.

Comment: You may wish to choose a different username, as there is already a long-term contributor to this site with the same name. (The software unfortunately does not automatically check during signing up if the name one wants to use is already taken.)

Comment: Words are used in different ways in different registers. The man on the Clapham omnibus's definition of 'hurricane' may be different from, even conflict with, that of a trained meteorologist, though supporting evidence might well be found for both. The more accurate usages may well involve 'stipulative definitions'; people thinking that they hold **the** right definition may end up arguing endlessly. Terms need defining where there is genuine ambiguity. // The difficult situations arise when different domains don't seek common ground.

Comment: @jsw29 — Really? WTF?

Comment: In plain English, confidence is a human emotion, not something measured on a scientific scale. In plain English try: *Evidence supports that the condition is likely present in the subject.* (Code values would be *likely* and *unlikely*.)

Comment: I'm extremely confident that "confidence" is a vague term.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a minor but important misunderstanding here. There is a mathematics of probability (likeliness), sometimes called (misleadingly) *chance*.  Given sufficient reliable information, we can measure how likely an event of outcome is.  For example, if I roll a cubic (six-sided) die, on a level even surface, the probability (or chance) of it coming up '1' is exactly one in six (or 16.67% to two decimal points of accuracy).

The fact that this is a measure of the 'probability' of throwing a '1', does not mean that a '1' is literally 'probable' for any individual throw of a die.  Probability is on a sliding scale from low to high.  So the probability of throwing a '1' on a die is quite low.

If you check the weather forecast on your mobile phone, you might see that it usually shows the probability of rain as a percentage, which varies between 5% and 10%, depending on the agency involved (I use the British Meteorological Office).  So if you are planning to go out for a picnic, you can check these to see whether it might rain.

The difference between throwing a die and forecasting rain wide as can be.  The probability of throwing a '1' is purely mathematical. Also, whether it falls that way on any one occasion is a matter pure chance (unless the die is dishonestly weighted in some way).

Whether the weather turns out exactly as forecast is not a matter of chance.  The science is well understood and becomes more and more accurate all the time.  We are pretty close to having access to all the evidence needed, even though the future interactions of the various factors does not allow certainty.

Predicting how voters will vote in an election is harder still.  It is based on polling (asking people how they intend to vote). The pollsters do not ask every voter for their intentions.  So they take ***samples*** of the electorate.  And the question arises whether any sample is ***sufficient*** in number or  ***representative*** in relation to the ages and economic and political backgrounds of the people sampled.  The more numerous the sample and the more representative of the range of age, education, employment, etcetera the more we can be *confident* in the prediction made is accurate.  A *confidence level* is a calculation of how *reliable* a sample has been taken.  Most polls, by the way, do not predict outcomes.  We might be seeing figures in the UK of 41% for one of the major parties, 34% for the other and the rest distributed among other parties. But how do we know that the sample is not made up mainly of people over fifty years of age (a high proportion of which tend to vote to the right of centre) or under forty (of whom a high proportion are inclined towards the left)?  Is size of the sample sufficient? And so on.  So the question arises, how confident can we be in the size of the sample?

> How confident can we be that the sample is balanced?  That is called the 'confidence level'.  How much room for error is there?

Dictionaries vary in their handling the idea of a 'confidence level'.  The online version of the Cambridge English Dictionary is aware of the existence of the expression but says:

> confidence level isn’t in the Cambridge Dictionary yet. You can help?

Collins defines it as a specialised "statistical" usage as:

> a measure of the reliability of a result. A confidence level of 95 per cent or 0.95 means that there is a probability of at least 95 per cent that the result is reliable.

Comment: 'A confidence level of 95 per cent or 0.95 means that there is a probability of at least 95 per cent that the result is reliable'  involves defining 'probability' in the first place. Theoretical probability is not, to my understanding, applicable rigorously to any true-life situations (there's no such thing as a truly fair dice; picture cards tend to stick together preferentially ...). And empirical probabilities always change as a function of actual historical sample considered.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Yes, I had considered making that reservation / explanation, but I do not think that 'confidence level' applies to rolling a die.  Strictly, the rolling of a die probability is pure maths and is not a matter of statistics.  Unlike weather forecasts and intelligence tests, it is not about sampling.  So it would be misleading to suggest that I could bet my house on getting a '1' at least once out of six rolls.  I just checked Merriam Webster, which does not have 'level' but has 'confidence interval'.  MW treats it as a specialist usage.  I'll have a further think

Comment: When I taught maths, there was an attempt to couch empirical probability questions in terms of idealised situations (a 'fair' dice [more common, I believe, nowadays], a perfectly balanced roulette wheel ...). This could cause problems rather than make it easier for the brighter kids.

Comment: I'm really just trying to establish whether there is a widespread impression that "confidence" implies "certainty." I think not, but I'm interested in what others think.

Comment: @ Jay  I am not sure that is strictly a matter of dictionary definitions.  What I would say is that the answer is that it may depend on the standards being applied.  If you are steeped in mathematics, like one commenter, or logic, like me you would accept that mathematical and logical theorems are certain in a way that factual propositions cannot be.  First in these, two areas certainty is a property not of states of mind but of propositions.  '5+7=12' and '(P or Q) entails (not-P entails Q)'.  In both cases you cannot deny them without contradicting yourself.  However, (continued)

Comment: @ Jay However, we do in the 'real world' use the word 'certain' in terms of 'feeling certain' about states of affairs past, present or future.  'Confidence', on the other hand, is used exclusively to describe states of mind, or did before this statistical use becamse established.  Even now 'confidence levels (or intervals)' strike a clever balance.  It tells us roughly how confident we can be.  Are the two words 'confident' and 'certain', when applied to states of mind, synonymous?  I would say 'no', but many would disagree.  Given the choice a politician would prefer 'certain', I think.